# Shuffle array with exceptions

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a way to shuffle all elements in an array with the exception of a specified index using the `shuffle` function?

Without having to manually write a method, does Ruby support anything similar?

For example, say I have an array of integers:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want to shuffle the elements in any random order but leave the first int in its place. The final result could be something like:

```
=> [1,4,3,2,5]
```

Just as long as that first element remains in its place. I've obviously found workarounds by creating my own methods to do this, but I wanted to see if there was some sort of built in function that could help cut down on time and space.

Comment: According to the [shuffle documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-shuffle), you can't do it with a single built-in Ruby function.  There are certainly a number of one-line solutions that you could find, though.

Comment: Maybe you can pass a custom random object, that doesn't shuffle specific indices?

Comment: Why don't you show us an example of what you mean by providing some input data and how you want it randomized instead of asking us to imagine it?

Comment: I see from the C source that Ruby does a number of pairwise exchanges, based on randomly-selected indices. so it wouldn't be hard to modify that to just skip exchanges that involved a particular index, though deleting a card, shuffling and putting it back in at the same location is pretty easy. I expect you know all this, though. By the way, is this for your Wednesday night poker group? If the card you don't want moved is on the bottom of the deck, that would of course be easier.

Comment: what would this mean? Do you mean that you want to remove a particular index from the array, shuffle the remainder, and then re-insert the removed element at its original position?

Comment: haha @CarySwoveland thanks for the idea... maybe i'll retry my luck at video poker. I will make an edit to the question to include a short example.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Based on the latest [Ruby documentation of Array.shuffle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) the only argument it accepts is random number generator. So you will need to write your own method - here's my take on it:

```
module ArrayExtender
  def shuffle_except(index)
    clone = self.clone
    clone.delete_at(index)
    clone.shuffle.insert(index, self[index])
  end
end

array = %w(a b c d e f)

array.extend(ArrayExtender)

print array.shuffle_except(1) # => ["e", "b", "f", "a", "d", "c"]
print array.shuffle_except(2) # => ["e", "a", "c", "b", "f", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function. It's still pretty easy to do that:

**first element**

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

hold = arr.shift
# => 1

arr.shuffle.unshift(hold)
# => [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

**specific index**

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
index = 2

hold = arr.delete_at(index)
# => 3

arr.shuffle.insert(index, hold)
# => [5, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```